# Mocking sqlite3 fetchone() in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlite, mocking

I've gone through some of the previous questions on here about mocking sqlite3 in python when doing unit tests, and unfortunately none of them have helped me be able to successfully mock the result from fetchone().

The following is a quick test example I put together to try and get it working:

TETS.PY

```
import unittest
import sqlite3
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class Foo: 

    def checkActive(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('lll.db')
        cur = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM SQLITE_MASTER")
        value = cur.fetchone()
        return value


class test_Foo(TestCase):

    @patch('tets.sqlite3')
    def test_shortTest(self, mock_sql):
        mock_sql.connect().cursor().fetchall.return_value = ('Test',)

        test_class = Foo()
        return_mock = test_class.checkActive()
        print(return_mock)

if __name__ == '__main__':  # pragma: no cover -> local unittest main call
    unittest.main()
```

I've tried variations of the above, as well as patching tets.sqlite3.connect and going from there but I always either of the below as result:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\z003uwfm\Desktop\tets.py"
<MagicMock name='connect().execute().fetchone()' id='45622576'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.016s

OK

[Running] python -u "c:\Users\z003uwfm\Desktop\tets.py"
None
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.021s

OK
```

Does anyone have a real working example where they were able to mock the return from either fetchone() or fetchall()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After further tinkering I found the following to be working:

```
@patch('sqlite3.connect')
def test_shortTest(self, mock_sql):
    mock_sql.return_value.execute.return_value.fetchone.return_value = ('Test',)
    test_class = Foo()
    return_mock = test_class.checkActive()
    print(return_mock)
```

All the other code remains the same as per the original post. Hope this helps others out if they ever have to come across this!